# Adding an html element dynamically and applying bindings to it

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to create an input-text box dynamically and trying to add bindings to it in `javascript` code as shown in the code.
In the UI, I can see the text-box. But unfortunately the binding is not applied. Please guide me how to make this work. Thanks.

***Code :***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function viewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.rolefilter = ko.observable("");

    self.role_hdr_func = function(context) {
        var filter = $(document.createElement('input'));

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(filter, {
            value : self.rolefilter,
            valueUpdate : 'afterkeydown'
        });

        var parentElement = $(context.headerContext.parentElement);
        parentElement.append(filter);
    };
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

Comment: Remove the jQuery wrapping around the createElement, applyBindingsToNode accepts a DOM node, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @adeneo This should be an answer, not a comment. Did the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/stnfT/) if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more powerful way of injecting HTML with KO is to use a custom string source for the template engine.

You can look at my combobox to see how its done,

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js#L344

Basically you implement your own string source like this

```
//string template source engine
var stringTemplateSource = function (template) {
    this.template = template;
};

stringTemplateSource.prototype.text = function () {
    return this.template;
};

var stringTemplateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();
stringTemplateEngine.makeTemplateSource = function (template) {
    return new stringTemplateSource(template);
};
```

Then you can use `ko.renderTemplate` to render the string

```
ko.renderTemplate(template, bindingContext.createChildContext(data), { templateEngine: stringTemplateEngine }, element, "replaceChildren");
```

`{ templateEngine: stringTemplateEngine }` is important, it tells KO to use your string source instead of the default script tag source.